# asynchronously call multiple GET requests from Ruby

Tags: ruby, asynchronous

I have a bunch of web requests I am making in parallel right now using the parallel gem. This is causing all kinds of memory issues due to vfork. These web requests take around 30 seconds each. Is there a way I can queue them all up asynchronously and have them start at the same time without using the parallel gem?

Right now I use Faraday to do the web requests. The code for each request looks like this:

```
conn = Faraday.new(url: TRIGGER_URL)
conn.post do |req|
  req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  req.options.timeout = 540
  req.body = {auth_key: AUTH_KEY, image_url: image_url, space_id: space_id, scene_num: scene_num, cylinder_mode: cylinder_mode}.to_json
end.body
```

Comment: Have you tried Typhoeus::Hydra? https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#making-parallel-requests

Comment: Consider using an asynchronous job processor like [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The async-http gem did exactly what I want.

https://github.com/socketry/async-http